# JavaFX - Better way to add database information from two sources into a TableView (MVC)

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, javafx, model-view-controller

I'm building an MVC application with IntelliJ IDEA which is actually quite simple. Nevertheless, I'm struggling with the TableView control and here is why :
I have a transaction class which contains information about the date, the name of the transaction...

```
//Database data
private int idSoin;
private String nom;
private Date date;
private BigDecimal chfBrut;
private BigDecimal chfNet;
private String paiement;
private int fkCategorie;
private int fkCollaborateur;
private int fkLivreDeCaisse;
```

All are accessed with getters/setters.

Then, I store multiple transactions in a List.

```
public  List<MouvementSoin> recupererLesMouvementsDuTableauSoin()throws SQLException{
    List<MouvementSoin> listMouvementsSoin = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "select * from mouvementsoin";

    try {
        conn = ouvrirLaConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            MouvementSoin Soin = new MouvementSoin();
            Soin.setIdSoin(rs.getInt(1));
            Soin.setDate(rs.getDate(2));
            Soin.setNom(rs.getString(3));
            Soin.setChfBrut(rs.getBigDecimal(4));
            Soin.setChfNet(rs.getBigDecimal(5));
            Soin.setPaiement(rs.getString(6));

            Soin.setFkCategorie(rs.getInt(7));
            Soin.setFkCollaborateur(rs.getInt(8));
            Soin.setFkLivreDeCaisse(rs.getInt(9));

            listMouvementsSoin.add(Soin);
        }

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(stmt != null)
        {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if(conn!= null)
        {
            conn.close();
        }
        if(rs != null)
        {
            rs.close();
        }
    }

    return listMouvementsSoin;
}
```

Everything is fine but now comes the problem. In fact, in the controller I have to display the information in a TableView but I don't want to display the foreign keys of course but the name related to them.

```
private void remplirTableauSoinAvecBDD(){
    List<MouvementSoin> listViewSoin = new ArrayList<>();
    ObservableList<MouvementSoin> ObsListRsltBdd = null;
    try {
        listViewSoin = model.recupererLesMouvementsDuTableauSoin();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*for(MouvementSoin mouv : listViewSoin)
    {
        try {
            mouv.setNomCollab(model.getCollaborateur(mouv.getFkCollaborateur()).toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/

    tableColumnSoinDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
    tableColumnSoinNom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nom"));
    tableColumnSoinBrut.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("chfBrut"));
    tableColumnSoinNet.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("chfNet"));
    tableColumnSoinPaiement.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("paiement"));
    //tableColumnSoinCollaborateur.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nomCollab"));


    ObsListRsltBdd = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listViewSoin);

    if(ObsListRsltBdd.size() != 0)
    {
        tableViewSoin.setItems(ObsListRsltBdd);
    }
}
```

In the code above I have commented out the way I've planned to do it. I'll explain myself. I wanted to add properties in the transaction class in order to retrieve the data related to the foreign keys and add them afterwards in a foreach loop. But I don't feel like it is the right thing to do since I want to have buttons in the row on top of that as shown in the next picture.
[Final TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDGO3.png)

PS: In Java swing it was very easy to have this working since you could access the rows.

Thank you for reading

Comment: If the data has a relationship in the database, why not do a query that returns all and only the necessary data?

Comment: Instead of storing foreign keys why don't you store the objects reference directly, for instance instad of `int fkCategorie` it will be `Categorie categorie;`. Also please consider using an ORM like Hibernate for instance it will make this task much more easier.

Comment: I could be wrong but it sounds to me like you need to brush up on your `SQL`. Find out how to pull the data you need using a query. Make sure your object/model mirrors the information from the query.

Comment: Could you post the table structure of the database you are pulling info from?

Comment: If I understand correctly you would change the properties in the transaction(MouvementSoin) class and replace with the data directly instead of the foreign key? If so do I fill the information in "recupererLesMouvementsDuTableauSoin()" part of the Model(MVC)? Furthermore, would I add constructors for the delete and modify buttons in the transaction class aswell and add the listeners in the controller part? PS : I have to keep the foreign keys for inserting values later on @RedaMeskali

Comment: Yes, my database has relationships and is well designed. I know SQL, I can directy pull the information instead of the foreign key. Would I edit the transcation(MouvementSoin) class though by adding properties for containing the name of the person and buttons? @Sedrick

Comment: If you need the foreign key, pull it also. Add it to your model but don't use it in the table. I am guessing that you will need to alter your transcation(MouvementSoin) class. I don't know for sure. It would be nice to have a MCVE to work with.